# Xamarin.Forms Style Nested Properties

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am creating a Xamarin.Forms app, and I want to style all of my ImageButtons' FontImageSource.Color properties. I cannot figure out how to do this through a Style, since it seems I can't set the target type to FontImageSource or set Property="Source.Color" or Property="Source.FontImageSource.Color" or anything similar.

How can I use a Style to set the Color property of all ImageButtons' FontImageSource?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you could try the following code：

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ImageButton">
        <Setter Property="Source">
            <Setter.Value>
               <FontImageSource
                    FontFamily="ionicons"
                    Glyph="\uf10d"
                    Size="30" 
                    Color="Red"/>                  
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: This looks like it might do what I want, but when I try it and place this with my other Styles nothing changes. The color on the ImageButtons stays the default white.

Comment: Actually, we also should set other properties attach to FontImageSource in Style,  like Glyph, Size. And if we set FontimageSource in other places, the Style also doesn't work. I update my answer.

Comment: This makes the style useless, though. Not all of my buttons have identical properties. Only the color and font family (and any default properties I never explicitly set) are identical across all buttons.

Comment: Give a ```x:Key="StyleName"``` to your style and apply the style to each ImageButton : ```<ImageButton ... Style="{StaticResource StyleName}" />```.